# Symbolic links in Yocto

Tags: symlink, yocto

I'm trying to make a sym link in Yocto to enable a systemd service that is not enabled by default (apache2, by the way). Here my post process command:

```
my_postprocess_function() {
    ln -s ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/apache2.service     
}

ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND += "my_postprocess_function; "
```

Of course the problem is the source file does not exists on the target, but if I use the right path (i.e. `/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service`) it does not exists on the dev machine and then the recipe fails.

What is the right approach to make a sym link in the rootfs (sub)paths?

Comment: @meuh your comment is actually the answer. If you write it I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you can create symbolic links to targets that don't exist. For example, try in any shell

```
ln -s /no/such/file xxx
```

and it will create link `xxx`. So
simply remove the first ${IMAGE_ROOTFS} from your command:

```
ln -s /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/apache2.service
```